# Ispconfig nginx redirecting to https

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx

I've deployed a CentOS server with ISPConfig and Nginx.

Also I was able to configure Nginx, manually (by editing /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.com.vhost), to redirect http requests to https:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;
    return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ..
}
```

As I edited the file manually,  every time I change a setting with ISPConfig, my vhost file gets overwritten and I lose my redirection's trick.

Do you know a way to config the redirection above using ISPConfig panel instead editing the nginx file manually ?

Thanks in avance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the more recent versions of ISPConfig, you can simply select the website to use SSL (and that means HTTPS, and optionally, SPDY or HTTP/2), with an additional checkbox to redirect all HTTP requests permanently to HTTPS, and ISPConfig will automatically generate the vhosts files correctly.

For the sake of completude, this is what ISPConfig adds:

```
server {
        listen *:80;

        listen *:443 ssl;
                ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_certificate /var/www/clients/clientX/webY/ssl/your.web.site.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /var/www/clients/clientX/webY/ssl/your.web.site.key;

        server_name your.web.site www.your.web.site;

        root   /var/www/your.web.site/web/;

        if ($http_host = "www.your.web.site") {
            rewrite ^ $scheme://your.web.site$request_uri? permanent;
        }
        if ($scheme != "https") {
            rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
        }


        index index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've configured the redirection as the accepted answer suggested.

Also I've included an external config so I put all our manual configurations.

In our version of ISPConfig, I did this:

```
if ($scheme != "https") {
  rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
}

include /etc/nginx/sites-available/my-own-config.conf;
```

That way, ISPConfig won't break our configs.